# Find Date falls within Range

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a table containing 4 columns

```
Column 1: ID
column 2:EmpID
Column 3:startDate
Column 4:EndDate

DATA
 ID      EMPID       StartDate      EndDate
  1       223         2014-06-06    2014-06-10
  2       223         2014-08-11    2014-08-22
  1       224         2014-09-06    2014-09-10
  2       224         2014-12-11    2014-12-22
```

I want to write a query which will return true or false based on if a particular date falls within startDate and EndDate of a particular Employee

Example if we pass empID 223 and date  2014-08-13 the query should return true
but 
if we pass empID 223 and date  2014-08-23 the query should return false

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have "true" and "false" built in.  You can return 0/1 like this:

```
select (case when count(*) > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as TrueIs1
from t
where empId = @empId and
      @date between StartDate and EndDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN 
  empID = 223 AND '2014-08-23' BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
  THEN 'true'
  ELSE 'false'
END FROM data;
```